# Create inline menu with telegrambot using python

Tags: python-telegram-bot

I need help creating those two menu

1 - menu that update itself when a button is clicked and remove that button.
[firstmenu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xd2l.jpg)

2 - menu that have next previous button.
[second menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7qBc.jpg)

I try to check the update callback query  data and check if the button is their so I deleted the problem is it delete all button it show that I clicked all the button in the same time.
For the second menu I have no idea how.
I need like a clarification or a logic how it work so I can start from their.

Minimal example with code can help
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to create a simple but functioning example with your specifications as i understood them. There are a bunch of comments, but let me know if something is still not clear.

```py
from telegram import Update, InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from telegram.ext import CallbackContext, CommandHandler, CallbackQueryHandler, Updater
from telegram.error import BadRequest

REMOVE_BUTTONS_COUNT = 5
PAGES_COUNT = 10


def get_text_and_keyboard(page: int, removed_buttons: list):
    """Generates both the text and the inline keyboard to show to the user,
    based on the current page and on the buttons that have been removed
    """
    # Makes sure removed_buttons is a list
    text = f"You are on page {page + 1}" if page is not None else "You are on page 1"
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(
        [
            [InlineKeyboardButton(text=f"RESET", callback_data="reset")],
            *[  # Each element generated is a row, notice the * before the [
                # and the [] wrapping the InlineKeyboardButton
                [InlineKeyboardButton(text=f" button {i}", callback_data=f"rm_{i}")]
                for i in range(REMOVE_BUTTONS_COUNT)
                if i not in removed_buttons
            ],
            [  # All the pages are on the same row
                InlineKeyboardButton(text=f"{i + 1}", callback_data=f"go_{i}")
                for i in range(PAGES_COUNT)
                if i != page
            ],
        ]
    )
    return text, keyboard


def remove_query(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    """Removes a button"""
    # The data is in the form "rm_<number>"
    button_idx = int(update.callback_query.data.replace("rm_", ""))
    rm_buttons = context.user_data.get("removed_buttons", [])
    rm_buttons.append(button_idx)
    context.user_data["removed_buttons"] = rm_buttons

    # I'm only interested in the keyboard, for the text message doesn't change
    _, keyboard = get_text_and_keyboard(None, rm_buttons)
    context.bot.edit_message_reply_markup(
        chat_id=update.callback_query.message.chat_id,
        message_id=update.callback_query.message.message_id,
        reply_markup=keyboard,
    )


def reset_query(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    """Resets both buttons and pages"""
    context.user_data["removed_buttons"] = []
    context.user_data["page"] = 0

    text, keyboard = get_text_and_keyboard(None, [])

    try:
        context.bot.edit_message_text(
            chat_id=update.callback_query.message.chat_id,
            message_id=update.callback_query.message.message_id,
            text=text,
            reply_markup=keyboard,
        )
    except BadRequest:  # The message was already in the default state
        pass


def go_to_page_query(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    """Goes to the provided page"""
    # The data is in the form "go_<number>"
    new_page = int(update.callback_query.data.replace("go_", ""))
    context.user_data["page"] = new_page
    removed_buttons = context.user_data.get("removed_buttons", [])

    text, keyboard = get_text_and_keyboard(new_page, removed_buttons)

    context.bot.edit_message_text(
        chat_id=update.callback_query.message.chat_id,
        message_id=update.callback_query.message.message_id,
        text=text,
        reply_markup=keyboard,
    )


def menu_cmd(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    """Handles the /menu  command.
    Shows the inline keyboard

    Args:
        update: update event
        context: context passed by the handler
    """
    # Both could be put on context.bot_data, context.chat_data, in a file or a database
    # depending on your requirements.
    # You may also want to reset them here
    page = context.user_data.get("page", 0)
    removed_buttons = context.user_data.get("removed_buttons", [])

    text, keyboard = get_text_and_keyboard(page, removed_buttons)

    context.bot.send_message(
        chat_id=update.message.chat_id,
        text=text,
        reply_markup=keyboard,
    )


def main():
    """Main function"""
    updater = Updater("TOKEN")
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", menu_cmd))
    # Regex is used in the pattern to match the callback_data coming from the buttons
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(remove_query, pattern=r"^rm_*"))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(reset_query, pattern=r"^reset$"))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(go_to_page_query, pattern=r"^go_*"))

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you @tend for the good clarification, that  was what i'm locking for.I was able to create the first menu like you mention after reading many docs, but the second part (*[]) i understand it now thanks again ;).